# Interpreting EXISTS Keyword

Tags: sql, exists

If EXISTS keywords only evaluates to True or False why below query returns all specified columns with matched id instead of all specified columns?

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name
FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT id
    FROM retirees
    WHERE id = employees.id);
```

Because if it's the case then shouldn't be the query evaluated to this:

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name
FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS (
    TRUE);
```

Comment: Does `retirees` have an `id` column? If not, you're committing a classic mistake (because the subquery can happily reference `id` from the outer query, when it's not qualified). If that's not the problem, you probably need to explain more, with sample data, expected results, etc

Comment: `EXISTS` isn't simply returning `TRUE` as in  your second example. It is limiting the returned employees to those with an `id` matching a `retirees` entry. In other words, it is returning all `employees` where a matching entry in `retirees` *exists*. This is not the same as `WHERE TRUE`

Comment: Thanks h0r53. It's declarative style sometimes makes me confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `exists` is in a `corelated subquery`. The functioning of exists doesnt end but traced back until all the employees id are matched with retires table each time when it runs. Hence, you will get the o/p as all ids of employees that matches with retires.

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` isn't simply returning `TRUE` as in your second example. It is limiting the returned `employees` to those with an id matching a `retirees` entry. In other words, it is returning all `employees` where a matching entry in `retirees` *exists*. This is not the same as `WHERE TRUE`.

Although `EXISTS` has boolean properties, the evaluation of TRUE or FALSE in this example determines whether or not an entry of `employees` should be included in the results. The `WHERE TRUE` form will cause all rows of the employees table to return, which is certainly not what `EXISTS` is doing, as you can likely see from your query results.

You can think of `EXISTS` as a clause that will match a subset of the original dataset, based on the `EXISTS` condition.

Answer (score 0):

The First code will select to you all the rows from the employees that have the id into the table retirees. The filter will that.

If you want to see what records that aren't into retirees's table you should add `not`.

Like that:

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name
FROM employees
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id
    FROM retirees
    WHERE id = employees.id);
```